# java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Hi i am beginner and present I have installed Oracle 10g Express Edition Release 2 in my windows 7 64 bit OS and tried to execute Hibernate program but i am getting below exceptions can some one help me please

```
WARNING: Could not obtain connection metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:xe

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1933)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1216)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

### hibernate.cfg.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
 <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
 <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
 <property name="connection.username">scott</property>
 <property name="connection.password">tiger</property>
 <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
 <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 <mapping resource = "resources/Dept.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource = "resources/Employee.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource = "resources/Student.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: In windows go to Services and check whether OracleXETNSListener and OracleServiceXE are in running state.

Comment: in services tab there was no option  OracleServiceXE  for running it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138189/discussion-between-coolgirl-and-anil-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

It shows that your instance name is xe, make sure xe is that you have installed instance.

if not, change the instance name.

not server name.

Comment: how to find instance name?

Answer (score 0):

Error message shows that SID given is unknown. Please make sure that SID of installed instance is 'xe' by connecting to any schema and running any of query below

```
select instance from v$thread;

select name from v$database;
```

Or type on `sqlplus` command prompt

```
show parameter instance_name;
```